# Unit testing the active record models

Tags: unit-testing, scala, activerecord, playframework

I'm developing a simple application on Play framework using Scala. I use companion objects as DAOs of the models. Something like this:

```
case class User(
  @Key("_id") id: BSONObjectID,
  name: String,
  password: String,
  ...
)

object User {
  def insert(model: User) = ...
  def remove(model: User) = ...
  def save(model: User) = ...
  def findAll() = ...
  ...
}
```

It looks very simple and clear to me but I have some problems for testing. For example when I use "User.findAll()" in a controller action, I can't test a controller action in isolation (unit testing).

I used to implement very decoupled software when I was developing on .NET. For example I create a repository for each model and inject it into the controllers (or services and then inject services to controllers). Then it's very easy to mock a repository and test a controller. After migrating to Scala and Play I like this sort of simplicity which I saw in its beginners tutorial. I know I can use DI, cake pattern or other things in Scala but I think those decoupling and DI was overkill for such simple applications.

Now the question is that is there any way to test the application with such simple design? Please note that I'm NOT talking about integration tests but unit tests.

Comment: Have you checked the Unit testing section [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTest)?

Comment: Yes I do, as I said I'm familiar with SOLID principals but I want to have using testing with this type of design.

Comment: I mean; ... have unit testing with this type of design :D